# How to reset/remove the style attribute with JavaScript in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I've got a very simple web page spinner using the [Prototype JS framework](http://www.prototypejs.org/):

Frame `nav`:

```
Event.observe(
    'doit',
    'click',
    function(){
      parent.window.frames.cont.spinner.removeAttribute('style');
    },
    false);
```

Frame `cont` (this is the first element within the `<body>`):

```
<div id="spinner" style="display: none;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#spinner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: url(spinner.gif) transparent no-repeat center;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Quite simply, it's a fixed-position `<div>` centered on the `cont` frame, and hidden when the browser loads the page (also to avoid problems in non-JS browsers). When the user clicks a button in the `nav` frame, the `style` attribute is removed and the user sees the spinner until the next page takes over. This works just fine in Firefox, but IE 9 refuses to work. This is what I've found from their standard <kbd>F12</kbd> interface:

- There is only one element with ID `spinner`.
- Running `parent.window.frames.cont.spinner.removeAttribute('style')` or `parent.window.frames.cont.document.getElementById("spinner").removeAttribute("style")` in the *Console* tab returns `true` but results in the *next but one* element being hidden! This is not reflected in the *HTML* tab in any discernible way - The hidden element still has `style="display: block;"`.

I tried using Prototype's [show()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/show), and it worked in Firefox, but not in IE9...

Comment: document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block"

Comment: The DOM API (getAttribute/removeAttribute,etc) have historically had issues dealing with synthesized properties (the gap between the DOM text and the actual objects that can be accessed via JavaScript). This appears to be one such case. I *highly recommend* using CSS classes or "standard" CSS inline property manipulation.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `parent.window.frames.cont.spinner.style.display = 'block';` worked - Can you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to remove the style attribute, just set the "display" property to "block".

```
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why remove the style attribute when it's much easier to add/remove classes? And anyways, if all you're trying to do is show/hide a div, why not just change the "display" style property only?